# Create a dict from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dict from a list with Python 2.7

This is my list :

```
x = ['+proj=geos',
 'lon_0=86.5',
 'h=35785993.3373',
 'x_0=0',
 'y_0=0',
 'a=6378160',
 'b=6356775',
 'units=m',
 'no_defs ']
```

In every element from my list, there are my keys and my values separated with the char "=". 
As a result,  i want this :

```
d = {"+proj": "geos", "lon_0": "86.5", "h": "35785993.3373", "x_0": "0", "y_0": "0", "a": "6378160", "b": "6356775", "units": "m"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict` with a generator expression with `split` and a filter:

```
>>> dict(y.split("=") for y in x if "=" in y)
{'+proj': 'geos',
 'a': '6378160',
 'units': 'm',
 'b': '6356775',
 'y_0': '0',
 'x_0': '0',
 'h': '35785993.3373',
 'lon_0': '86.5'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
d = {}
for i in x:
    if '=' not in i: continue  # skip if no pair given
    key, value = i.split('=')  # split into pair
    d.update({key : value})    # update dict with pair
```

Comment: I Confirm, it's working with Python 2.7. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `d.update` seems a little bit out of proportion. `d[key] = value` will be enough.

Comment: @Matthias yes, you're right, defintly more suitable - still need to get rid of that habbit